# Having to hold links and webpages to open them

Tags: safari

I'm having to hold and press links in Safari to open the pages - I used to just touch it and it would open. I prefer the latter but how do change it back? I can't find any info online (probably because I don't know the correct terminology to perform an effective search).

Comment: Is this on iPhone or a Mac?

Comment: @user194756 I can't think of a way why this would happen. You should just by default tap quickly on the link to open the webpage. Is it pure iOS or jailbreak? Have you checked General>Accessibility. Tell us what is turned on in there from the list of options (most should be off).

Comment: I love you guys! I went to General - Accessibility and saw 3D Touch (which I turned off). Problem solved. It's not jailbroken for info if that helps anyone else.

Comment: Most importantly is [General>Accessibility>Touch Accommodations>Touch Accommodations + Hold Duration] both turned on? That seems to fit you context because the should be off in general.

Comment: @user194756 wait. Let me post this as an answer so you can accept it. The comments section is not the proper way to answer, but more for clarification p.

Comment: Yes you're right, they were all turned on. This has been driving me mad for over a year! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked your settings in General > Accessibilities? For most people, most of the options should be disabled (except for shaking the screen to undo an action which is by preference).

I have a possibility. Are General > Accessibility > Touch Accommodations > Touch Accommodations + Hold Duration both turned on? Because they make it so that you have to hold on the screen in order to register a touch. That seems to fit your context because they should be off in general.

Comment: Spot on! Solved - thanks so much for your time.

Comment: @user194756 I also thank you for ticking answers that answer your question.